# How do I fill everything over a straight line and under a curve?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I am using the Charts component in Windows Forms.

I create a `straight line` using

```
chart1.Series["Grenzwert"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, y));
chart1.Series["Grenzwert"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(maxwidth, y));
```

Also I plot a a series of points connected by a line, let's call it `curve`.

How do I show everything over `straight line` and under `curve` filled?

Column fills the whole area, not just above `straight line`.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an idea that use `SeriesChartType.Range` as follow.

```
private void UpdateChart(float straight_line, List<DataPoint> curve)
{
    float y = straight_line;    // YValue of the straight line
    var list = curve.ToList();  // Clone the curve

    int count = list.Count - 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)  // Calculate intersection point between the straight line and a line between (x0,y0) and (x1,y1) 
    {
        double x0 = list[i + 0].XValue;
        double y0 = list[i + 0].YValues[0];
        double x1 = list[i + 1].XValue;
        double y1 = list[i + 1].YValues[0];

        if ((y0 > y && y1 < y) || (y0 < y && y1 > y))
        {
            double x = (y - y0) * (x1 - x0) / (y1 - y0) + x0;

            list.Add(new DataPoint(x, y));
        }
    }

    list.Sort((a, b) => Math.Sign(a.XValue - b.XValue));

    chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
    chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Range;
    chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Red;
    chart1.Series[0].BorderColor = Color.Cyan;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        double xx = list[i].XValue;
        double yy = list[i].YValues[0];
        if (yy > y)
        {
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(xx, y, yy);
        }
        else
        {
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(xx, yy, yy);
        }
    }

    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines.Add(new StripLine { IntervalOffset = y, Interval = 0, BorderColor = Color.Orange, BorderWidth = 2 });

}
```

As in the below drawing to judge whether the straight line and a line between (x0,y0) and (x1,y1) intersect, case 1 is `(y0 < y && y1 > y)` and case 2 is `(y0 > y && y1 < y)` . In case 1 and case 2, they intersect each other. In case 3 and case 4, they don't intersect each other.

[image: the below drawing to judge whether the straight line and a line between (x0,y0) and (x1,y1) intersect]

Comment: It works but I don't understand what you are doing. Can you elaborate and create a function like `private void UpdateChart(float straight_line, List<DataPoint> curve)` like this http://pastebin.com/i6tf9iWA

Comment: Great. Can you elaborate how it works? Especially the `if ((y0 > y && y1 < y) || (y0 < y && y1 > y))` part.

Answer (score 7):

This is late and not really short but imo it is the best way to color areas in a chart.

The `Lines` and also the `Spline` charttypes can be very precisely colored by coding the `Paint` event with the right data. The necessary pixel values can be obtained by the axis function `ValueToPixelPosition`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465005/how-can-i-fill-the-areas-between-two-series-of-spline-or-line/37465012#37465012) for another example!

The following code is a little longer because we need to add certain points at the start **and** end of **both** the chart **and** each colored area. Other than that it is very straight forward: Create `GraphicsPaths` by adding the pixel coordinates with `AddLines` and fill the `GraphicsPaths` in the `Paint` event.

For testing and for fun I have added a movable `HorizontalLineAnnotation`, so I can see how the areas vary when I drag it up and down..:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The `Paint` event is rather simple; it refers to a `HorizontalLineAnnotation hl` :

```
private void chart1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    double limit = hl.Y;    // get the limit value
    hl.X = 0;               // reset the x value of the annotation

    List<GraphicsPath> paths = getPaths(chart1.ChartAreas[0], chart1.Series[0], limit);

    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(127, Color.Red)))
        foreach (GraphicsPath gp in paths)
            { e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, gp); gp.Dispose(); }
}
```

The code to get the paths is obviously way too long for comfort..:

```
List<GraphicsPath> getPaths(ChartArea ca, Series ser, double limit)
{
    List<GraphicsPath> paths = new List<GraphicsPath>();
    List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
    int first = 0;
    float limitPix = (float)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(limit);

    for (int i = 0; i < ser.Points.Count; i++)
    {
        if ((ser.Points[i].YValues[0] > limit) && (i < ser.Points.Count - 1))
        {
            if (points.Count == 0) first = i;  // remember group start
            // insert very first point:
            if (i == 0) points.Insert(0, new PointF( 
                 (float)ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(ser.Points[0].XValue), limitPix));

            points.Add( pointfFromDataPoint(ser.Points[i], ca)); // the regular points
        }
        else
        {
            if (points.Count > 0)
            {
                if (first > 0)  points.Insert(0, median(  
                                  pointfFromDataPoint(ser.Points[first - 1], ca),
                                  pointfFromDataPoint(ser.Points[first], ca), limitPix));
                if (i == ser.Points.Count - 1)
                {
                    if ((ser.Points[i].YValues[0] > limit)) 
                         points.Add(pointfFromDataPoint(ser.Points[i], ca));
                    points.Add(new PointF( 
                  (float)ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(ser.Points[i].XValue), limitPix));
                }
                else
                    points.Add(median(pointfFromDataPoint(ser.Points[i - 1], ca),
                                 pointfFromDataPoint(ser.Points[i], ca), limitPix));

                GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
                gp.FillMode = FillMode.Winding;
                gp.AddLines(points.ToArray());
                gp.CloseFigure();
                paths.Add(gp);
                points.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
    return paths;
}
```

It uses two helper functions:

```
PointF pointfFromDataPoint(DataPoint dp, ChartArea ca)
{
    return new PointF( (float)ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.XValue),
                       (float)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.YValues[0]));
}

PointF median(PointF p1, PointF p2, float y0)
{
    float x0 = p2.X - (p2.X - p1.X) * (p2.Y - y0) / (p2.Y - p1.Y);
    return new PointF(x0, y0);
}
```

The  `HorizontalLineAnnotation` is set up like this:

```
hl = new HorizontalLineAnnotation();
hl.AllowMoving = true;
hl.LineColor = Color.OrangeRed;
hl.LineWidth = 1;
hl.AnchorDataPoint = S1.Points[1];
hl.X = 0;
hl.Y = 0;         // or some other starting value..
hl.Width = 100;   // percent of chart..
hl.ClipToChartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[0].Name;  // ..but clipped
chart1.Annotations.Add(hl);
```

Comment: could you help in this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175238/stackedbar-borders-between-different-series

Comment: Such an awesome function! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows.

1. Set the column fill like you did before. Everything will be red.
2. Create a new column graph on the same chart.
3. Set its values to the same as your jagged line, but capped at the y value of the straight line you already have.
4. Set the fill colour for the columns to white. This will block out the red fill for any areas not between the lines.

Comment: Works but it blocks the grid aswell as all other curves behind that. I need to draw only the area that is interesting instead of using visual tricks...

Comment: Hmm. Not sure there is a way without visual tricks. Let's hope another poster has a better solution.