# StackedBar borders between different series

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, charts, mschart

What i want is to set borders between two series in StackedBar Like this image The bold black line between blue and green

[image]

I can not figure out any idea to specify the border, i tried to set the borders to the series throuh this code

```
                chart.Series["series0"].BorderWidth = 2;
                chart.Series["series0"].BorderColor = Color.Black;
                chart.Series["series0"].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
```

but this the result i got

[image] [image]

Here's my code

```
 double l = Convert.ToDouble(query1[i - 1][0]) - 10;
                    string n = query1[i - 1][1];
                    int count = 0;
                for (double t = l; t < l + 10; t++)
                {

                        //Next line Calc. the occurence of character in a text file
                        count = n.Split('C').Length - 1;
                        //Multiple the occurence by 10 so it become percent
                        chart.Series["series0"].Points.AddXY(t, count * 10);
                        chart.Series["series0"]["PointWidth"] = "1";
                        chart.Series["series0"].BorderWidth = 2;
                        chart.Series["series0"].BorderColor = Color.Black;
                        chart.Series["series0"].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;


                        count = n.Split('o').Length - 1;
                        chart.Series["series1"].Points.AddXY(t, count * 10);
                        chart.Series["series1"]["PointWidth"] = "1";

                }
```

How to achieve the first pic effect using StackedBar ? , if i can not using StackedBar, what chart type you suggest to use ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no built-in chart elements that could easily be made into a borderline between those two **Series**. (Creating `LineAnnotations` to achieve this would be a nightmare..)

So the way to add the lines is to draw them onto the surface of the `Chart`. This is most naturally done in the `PostPaint` event, provided just for such adornments.

Here the `Axes` have handy functions to convert between the data values and the pixel positions. We need the `ValueToPixelPosition` method.

I will take you through variations of `Chart` drawing that gradually get a little more complicated as we approach the final version..:

Let's start with a simple example: Let's build and adorn a `StackedArea` chart; here is the drawing code:

```
private void chart2_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Series s = chart1.Series[0];
    ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
    var pp = s.Points.Select(x=>
        new PointF( (float)ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(x.XValue),
                    (float)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(x.YValues[0])  )   );

    if (s.Points.Count >  1) 
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.DarkOliveGreen, 4f))
            e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, pp.ToArray());
}
```

The `Points.Select` is really just a shorthand for a loop; so after creating the pixel point list we simply draw it.

Now, as you can see, as `StackedArea` chart is pointy and doesn't look like a `StackedBar` or `StackedColumn` chart. So let's cheat and 'rectify' the area chart by adding a few extra points:

```
void rectifyArea(Series s)
{
    for (int i = s.Points.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
        s.Points.InsertXY(i, i - 1, s.Points[i].YValues[0]);
}
```

Results:
[image][image]

Now that was not so hard; unfortunately you just can't turn a `StackedArea` to go from left to right instead of bottom-up. So we need to change the chart type to a `Bar` type eventually..

Here the challenge is to find the right upper and lower **corners** of those bars. We do have the `DataPoint` values, but these are in the **middle** of the bars. So we need to add/subtract **half** of the Bars' width to get the **corners**. For this we need the **width**.

While you have set it with the `PointWidth` property to  `1`, what we really need is the pixel width. We best get it by subtracting the pixel coordinates of two neighbouring points.

This makes the `PostPaint` event a little longer, but still not overly complicated; we will start with a `StackedColumn` chart, adding two corner points for each data point:

```
private void chart1_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Series s = chart1.Series[0];
    ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
    if (s.Points.Count <= 0) return;

    // calculate width of a column:
    int pp1 = (int)ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(s.Points[0].XValue);
    int pp2 = (int)ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(s.Points[1].XValue);
    float w2 = Math.Abs(pp2 - pp1) / 2f;

    List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Points.Count; i++)
    {
        DataPoint dp = s.Points[i];
        points.Add(new PointF( (int)ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.XValue) - w2,
                               (int)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.YValues[0]) ));

        points.Add(new PointF( (int)ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.XValue) + w2,
                               (int)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.YValues[0]) ));
    }

    if (points.Count > 1)
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.DarkOliveGreen, 4f))
            e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, points.ToArray());
}
```

Now this looks pretty much identical to our fake version of the 'rectified area chart'. What will we need to change to apply this to a `StackedBar` chart? Almost nothing! The only two things we need to take care of are

- the direction of the y-axis. Since the points move upward but the pixel coordinates of GDI+ graphhics move downwards we need to create the two cornerpoints in the reverse order.
- And we need to reverse the x- and y coodinates, as the axes are reversed for all types of `Bar` charts.

Here are the two stacked charts with a border:

[image][image]

This is the loop for the `StackBar` chart:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.Points.Count;  i++)
{
   points.Add(new PointF( (float)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(s.Points[i].YValues[0]),
                           (float)ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(s.Points[i].XValue) + w2));
   points.Add(new PointF( (float)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(s.Points[i].YValues[0]),
                           (float)ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(s.Points[i].XValue) - w2));
}
```

Note that I am drawing with a fixed pen width of 4 pixels. To make it scale with the `Chart` you may want to calculate the pen width dynamically..

**Update**

[image]

To draw borders on top of several series you can put the code into a loop like this:

```
private void chart1_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Chart  chart = chart1;
    Series s0 = chart.Series[0];
    ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas[0];

    // calculate width of a bar:
    int pp1 = (int)ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(s0.Points[0].XValue);
    int pp2 = (int)ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(s0.Points[1].XValue);
    float delta = Math.Abs(pp2 - pp1) / 2f;

    for (int s = 0; s < chart.Series.Count; s++)
    {
       List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
       for (int p = 0; p < chart.Series[s].Points.Count; p++)
       {
         DataPoint dp = chart.Series[s].Points[p];
         double v = GetStackTopValue(chart, s, p);
         points.Add(new PointF((float)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(v),
                                (float)ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.XValue) + delta));
         points.Add(new PointF((float)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(v),
                               (float)ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.XValue) - delta));
        }
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.DarkOliveGreen, 3f))
            e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, points.ToArray());
    }
}

double GetStackTopValue(Chart chart, int series, int point)
{
    double v = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < series + 1; i++)
        v += chart.Series[i].Points[point].YValues[0];
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot works good except for the last couple lines about stackedbar
need to reverse the sign ,... (-) sign in first line and (+) in the second. 

Also is it usable for more series ?? if i want to separate like 4 series beside each other ,... should i take care of something or just same method in the code ?

Comment: sorrry i hit enter before i compelete the comment ,.. i edited the comment again ,..all works fine now

Comment: Yes the same principle can be applied to many series. This is what you need to change: Since the y-values are stacked you need to feed their __sums__ into the conversion function. Here is an example of two series: `points2.Add(new PointF((float)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(dp2.YValues[0] + dp1.YValues[0]),...` - dp1 and dp2 are the datapoints from the 1st two series. For more you better use a loop!

Comment: yes worked perfect for more series ,.. thanks again for help

Comment: I have added a loop verson ;-)

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for :D