# smoothing stacked line graph

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, mschart

I have a c# Windows forms application that generates a stacked line graph using the standard MS Chart control, as in the below example.

Is there a way of "smoothing" the lines by formatting the series or some other property?

Looking at MSDN and Google I can't seem to find a way to do this, in Excel there a `series.Smooth` property...

I have I missed it or is it not possible?

[image]

Comment: Try `SplineArea` chart type.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the pointy edges you could calculate the datapoints and owner-draw the areas as filled pathes made up of curves and lines. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175238/stackedbar-borders-between-different-series/38261691?s=1|0.3676#38261691) is an example of calculating stacked coordinates..

Comment: @jstreet, unfortunately this is not a stacked graph else it would have been great however the results looked fun! thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @TaW thank you for the suggestions, I was hoping for a simple solution :(

Comment: The SplineArea data can be calculated to resemble your StackedArea chart!

Comment: @TaW thanks just looking into what that would entail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you liked the smooth look of the `SplineAreas` you can calculate the necessary values to get just that look:

[image]

A few notes:

- I have reversed the order of the series; many ways to get the colors right.. (Instead one probably should accumulate in reverse)
- The stacked `DataPoints` need to be **aligned**, as usual and any **empty** `DataPoints` should have their `Y-Values` to be `0`.
- Of course in the new series you can't access the actual data values any longer as you now have the accumulated values instead; at least not without reversing the calulation. So if need them keep them around somewhere. The new `DataPoints' Tag` property is one option..
- You can control the ' smoothness'  of each `Series` by setting its `LineTension` custom attribute:

---

```
 chart2.Series[0].SetCustomProperty("LineTension", "0.15");
```

[image]
Here is the full example code that creates the above screenshots calculating a  'stacked' `SplineArea chart2` from the data in a `StackedArea chart1`:

```
// preparation
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    Series s = chart1.Series.Add("S" + i);
    s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedArea;

    Series s2 = chart2.Series.Add("S" + i);
    s2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.SplineArea;

}

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)   // some test data
{
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, Math.Abs(Math.Sin(i / 8f)));
    chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(i, Math.Abs(Math.Sin(i / 4f)));
    chart1.Series[2].Points.AddXY(i, Math.Abs(Math.Sin(i / 1f)));
    chart1.Series[3].Points.AddXY(i, Math.Abs(Math.Sin(i / 0.5f)));
}

// the actual calculations:

int sCount = chart1.Series.Count; 
for (int i = 0; i < chart1.Series[0].Points.Count ; i++)
{
    double v = chart1.Series[0].Points[i].YValues[0];
    chart2.Series[sCount - 1].Points.AddXY(i, v);
    for (int j = 1; j < sCount; j++)
    {
        v += chart1.Series[j].Points[i].YValues[0];
        chart2.Series[sCount - j - 1].Points.AddXY(i, v);
    }
}

// optionally control the tension:
chart2.Series[0].SetCustomProperty("LineTension", "0.15");
```