# C# Win.Forms line chart with filling above

Tags: c#, .net, forms, charts, line

I am using C# win.forms and chart class to draw few line functions on one chart, but I need to fill everything above/under them, but have no idea have how to do that. I visualised my intention on quick paint (I am not Da Vinci) image. Point marked on chart is a solution from my algorithm.

Is there any way to do that in chart class? Or maybe any other libary/way to do it? Thanks!

[image]

Edit:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Series sps1, sps2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sps1 = new Series();
        sps2 = new Series();

        sps1.Name = "Super series 1";
        sps2.Name = "Super series 2";

        sps1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
        sps2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;

        sps1.Points.AddXY(0, 0);
        sps1.Points.AddXY(10, 10);

        sps2.Points.AddXY(0, 10);
        sps2.Points.AddXY(10, 0);

        chart1.Series[0] = sps1;
        chart1.Series.Add(sps2);

    }


    private void chart1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // we assume two series variables are set..:
        if (sps1 == null || sps2 == null) return;

        // short references:
        Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
        Axis ay = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;

        // now we convert all values to pixels
        List<PointF> points1 = sps1.Points.Select(x =>
           new PointF((float)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(x.XValue),
                      (float)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(x.YValues[0]))).ToList();

        List<PointF> points2 = sps2.Points.Select(x =>
           new PointF((float)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(x.XValue),
                      (float)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(x.YValues[0]))).ToList();

        // one list forward, the other backward:
        points2.Reverse();

        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
        gp.FillMode = FillMode.Winding;  // the right fillmode

        // it will work fine with either Splines or Lines:
        if (sps1.ChartType == SeriesChartType.Spline) gp.AddCurve(points1.ToArray());
        else gp.AddLines(points1.ToArray());
        if (sps2.ChartType == SeriesChartType.Spline) gp.AddCurve(points2.ToArray());
        else gp.AddLines(points2.ToArray());

        // pick your own color, maybe a mix of the Series colors..
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(66, Color.DarkCyan)))
            e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, gp);
        gp.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Here is my simple form with two lines, but I recive no effect like in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465005/how-can-i-fill-the-areas-between-two-series-of-splines-or-lines/37465012#37465012), just 2 lines and thats it. What am I missing?

```
using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(66, Color.DarkCyan)))
        e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, gp);
    gp.Dispose();
```

And how it works, that you are disposing graphics gp to current chart? Because thats what I probably missing? Thanks

@Taw, could you please explain, what do you exactly mean? I just debugged the application plotting two 100 points parabola's  crossing each other, and realised it is even not entering chart1_Paint method.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Series sps1, sps2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sps1 = new Series();
        sps2 = new Series();

        sps1.Name = "Super series 1";
        sps2.Name = "Super series 2";

        sps1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
        sps2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;


        for (double i = 0; i < 10; i += 0.1)
        {
            sps1.Points.AddXY(i, 0.2*i*i);
        }


        for (double i = 0; i < 10; i += 0.1)
        {
            sps2.Points.AddXY(i, -0.2 * i*i+20);
        }

        chart1.Series[0] = sps1;
        chart1.Series.Add(sps2);
    }

    private void chart1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // we assume two series variables are set..:
        if (sps1 == null || sps2 == null) return;

        // short references:
        Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
        Axis ay = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;

        // now we convert all values to pixels
        List<PointF> points1 = sps1.Points.Select(x =>
           new PointF((float)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(x.XValue),
                      (float)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(x.YValues[0]))).ToList();

        List<PointF> points2 = sps2.Points.Select(x =>
           new PointF((float)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(x.XValue),
                      (float)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(x.YValues[0]))).ToList();

        // one list forward, the other backward:
        points2.Reverse();

        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
        gp.FillMode = FillMode.Winding;  // the right fillmode

        // it will work fine with either Splines or Lines:
        if (sps1.ChartType == SeriesChartType.Spline) gp.AddCurve(points1.ToArray());
        else gp.AddLines(points1.ToArray());
        if (sps2.ChartType == SeriesChartType.Spline) gp.AddCurve(points2.ToArray());
        else gp.AddLines(points2.ToArray());

        // pick your own color, maybe a mix of the Series colors..
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(66, Color.DarkCyan)))
            e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, gp);
        gp.Dispose();
    }

}
```

[2 parabolas plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STM3D.png)

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465005/how-can-i-fill-the-areas-between-two-series-of-splines-or-lines/37465012?s=52|17.4851#37465012) may be of interest. And for a more complicated example look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001202/how-do-i-fill-everything-over-a-straight-line-and-under-a-curve/37488737#37488737) - Before filling you need to learn how to draw the lines. hint: You probably want to calculate the axis/chartarea intersections. For more spcific help you will need to be (a lot) more specific on your input.

Comment: Or you could go for `SeriesChartType.Area`..

Comment: Um, ok, what are you missing?? Also: I really meant what I wrote: _You will need to be (a lot) more specific on your input._

Comment: Resolved by adding
chart1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.chart1_Paint);
I think that will be enough to use in my purpose.

Thank you, @TaW!