# How can I fill the area(s) between two Series of Splines or Lines with two different colors?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a chart like this:
[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPC0e.jpg)

I want to fill the area of the spline above the horizontal series green and under the horizontal series red like this paint:
[painted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdsdx.jpg)

I tried the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465005/how-can-i-fill-the-areas-between-two-series-of-splines-or-lines/37465012) but it will only helps me filling with one color :/  as `PaintEvent` i use:

```
private void dgv_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e){

// short references:
Axis ax = dgv.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
Axis ay = dgv.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;

// now we convert all values to pixels
List<PointF> points1 =  dgv.Series[0].Points.Select(x=>
    new PointF((float)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(x.XValue), 
               (float)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(x.YValues[0]))).ToList();

List<PointF> points2 =  dgv.Series[1].Points.Select(x=>
    new PointF((float)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(x.XValue), 
               (float)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(x.YValues[0]))).ToList();

// one list forward, the other backward:
points2.Reverse();

GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
gp.FillMode = FillMode.Winding;  // the right fillmode

// it will work fine with either Splines or Lines:
if (dgv.Series[0].ChartType == SeriesChartType.Spline )   gp.AddCurve(points1.ToArray());
else gp.AddLines(points1.ToArray());
if (dgv.Series[1].ChartType == SeriesChartType.Spline) gp.AddCurve(points2.ToArray());
else gp.AddLines(points2.ToArray()); 

// pick your own color, maybe a mix of the Series colors..
using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(66, Color.DarkCyan)))
    e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, gp);
gp.Dispose();}
```

Maybe someone has a suitable hint for me...

Comment: Did you also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001202/how-do-i-fill-everything-over-a-straight-line-and-under-a-curve/37488737#37488737) ?

Comment: jap and this also works fine for one color, exactly like the example. but i don't understand how to edit it for the second color below the horizontalannotation :/

Comment: when i copy the code from your example two times and change the operator from ">" to "<" at the second run, it will be correct...but this is very uncomfortable :/

Comment: I would indeed __call `getPaths`__ it twice, adding a bool to switch < and > and thus get two lists. Then run the loop for each list. not too bad imo..

Comment: @TaW: Great hint...this will work fine :)